# Sorting Datatgrid

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting

I have a DataGrid in WPF app with several columns, including a Score column.I want the data to be sorted by the Score.

Is it possible sort DataGrid ?

Wpf Code:

```
        <DataGrid Name="datagrid_BergretterHighscore" Margin="5,5,5,5" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Vorname}" Header="Vorname" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Nachname}" Header="Nachname" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Score}" Header="Score" SortDirection="Descending" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
         
        </DataGrid>
```

C# Code:

```
 namespace PistenDIenstListe_Views.HighscorePage
 {
    

    public partial class Highscore : Page
    {
        private static PistenDienstDB context = new PistenDienstDB();
        BergretterData bergretterData = new BergretterData(context);

        public Highscore()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            datagrid_BergretterHighscore.ItemsSource = bergretterData.Read();
            datagrid_BergretterHighscore.IsReadOnly = true;

        }


    }
 }
```

Comment: See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-group-sort-and-filter-data-in-the-datagrid-control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the default `ICollectionView` of the `ItemsControl` ([Collection views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-6.0#collection-views)). Since you handle the `DataGrid` directly, you can reference the view returned by the `ItemsControl.Items` property for this purpose:

```cs
public partial class Highscore : Page
{
  private static PistenDienstDB context = new PistenDienstDB();
  BergretterData bergretterData = new BergretterData(context);

  public Highscore()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    dataGrid_BergretterHighscore.ItemsSource = bergretterData.Read();
    dataGrid_BergretterHighscore.IsReadOnly = true;

    // Sort the DataGrid programmatically
    var sortDescription = new SortDescription(nameof(MyDataObject.Score), ListSortDirection.Descending);
    dataGrid_BergretterHighscore.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(sortDescription);
  }
}
```